# How to fix mongos post request from postman

Tags: mongodb, post, postman

I am new ,i am having problem posting some data on mongodb model(users) from postman[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loNG6.jpg)

Expecting a successful post request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the latest version of Express which is (Express v4.16.0 and higher) Use this in your server.js file: ----->

```
const express = require('express');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
// For Express version less than 4.16.0 // ------------------------------------

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
```